# Tokbox stop screen share not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, stream, tokbox

I am using tokbox screenshare extension to share screen with other publishres it stops screen share but on chrome,default chrome popup never close and it should close sutomatically when i stop screen share by session.unpublish(ScreenPublisher);

Here is my code to stop screen share:

session.unpublish(ScreenPublisher);

Comment: Which popup are you referring to? Do you mean the popup that lets you pick which screen you want to share? Or the popup after you have picked the screen that says "<App Name> is sharing a window with <url>" and has a "Stop Sharing" button?

If it's the latter then that should go away when you unpublish. If it's the former then I have also noticed that not going away and that's a bug with Chrome. I would file a bug here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Yes I am talking about, screen that says "<App Name> is sharing a window with <url>" and has a "Stop Sharing" button popup

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Here are my steps:

1. Go to https://opentok-meet.herokuapp.com/testing
2. Click on the "Screen" button
3. Install the extension
4. Refresh the page
5. Click on "Screen" again.
6. Choose a screen to share
7. Click on the red "Screen" button to stop sharing (this calls session.unpublish)

Result: The popup at the bottom goes away as expected

Comment: Does this app use camera-filter API?

Comment: problem is not in code it is camera-filter API that prevents to remove "stop sharing" bar/popup.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the https://github.com/aullman/opentok-camera-filters library

It was not calling stop on the underlying stream when you unpublish. It should now be fixed with https://github.com/aullman/opentok-camera-filters/pull/14

Comment: NO, I am getting this error now :Failed to get access to your camera or microphone. Please check that your webcam is connected and not being used by another application and try again

Comment: Failed to get access to your camera or microphone. Please check that your webcam is connected and not being used by another application and try again

Comment: Also, I was showing exports already defined so i have changes this to exports_

Comment: But still getting this error:  
Failed to get access to your camera or microphone. Please check that your webcam is connected and not being used by another application and try again